# Count occurences where x % y == 0

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a function which accepts `*args` and would return a dictionary of keys from 1 to 9 and values how many numbers are divisible by those 1 to 9 without a remainder:

```
my_dict = {}
def myFunc(*args):
    for item in args:
        if (item % 2 == 0):
            my_dict[2] = number of times arguments were divisible by 2
                 if (item % 3 == 0):
                     my_dict[3] = number of times arguments were divisible by 3
       ...

myFunc(1,5,6,10,5,8)
```

I've tried this:

```
my_dict = {}
def myFunc(*args):
    x=0
    for item in args:
        if (item % 2) == 0:
           x+=1
           my_dict[2] = x
myFunc(1, 2, 3, 6, 8,10)
print(my_dict)
#{2: 4}
```

Which works for one number, not sure how I could elegantly fill the whole dictionary so it would look something like this when `1,2,3,4,4,5,10,16,20` is passed:

```
my_dict = {1:9, 2:6, 3:1, 4:4, 5:3, 6:0, 7:0, 8:1, 9:0}
```

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,4,5,10,16,20]

d = {i: sum(k % i == 0 for k in a) for i in range(1,10)}

d
# {1: 9, 2: 6, 3: 1, 4: 4, 5: 3, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 1, 9: 0}
```

or if you prefer,

```py
def myfun(*args):
    return {i: sum(k % i == 0 for k in args) for i in range(1,10)}

myfun(1,2,3,4,4,5,10,16,20)
# {1: 9, 2: 6, 3: 1, 4: 4, 5: 3, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 1, 9: 0}
```

Comment: What if arguments are not a list, or does that change nothing?

Comment: I edited my comment to be closer to your usage, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:-

```
def my_func(ls):
    res = {i:0 for i in range(1,10)}
    for l in ls:
        for i in range(1, 10):
            if l % i == 0:
                res[i] += 1

return res
```

```
print(my_func([1,2,3,4,4,5,10,16,20]))
```

Output will be like this -

```
{1:9, 2:6, 3:1, 4:4, 5:3, 6:0, 7:0, 8:1, 9:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use map to solve this .

```
my_dict = {}
def myFunc(*args):
   for y in range(1,10):
        my_dict[y] = sum(map(lambda number : number % y ==0, args))

myFunc(1, 2, 3, 6, 8,10)
print(my_dict)
```